# post request in jquery

Tags: jquery, api

How i can do the post request in jquery for this API:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems?fields=lineItems&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

In my earlier code i am working with the get request it is working fine.So now i need to remove the complete get request and i need to call the post request for the following API.So basically i need to call a post request and i need to download that data to csv file.Downloading to csv code is working fine.can you please help me how to do that post request for the following API.My code is as shown below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "youtubeData.csv" });'>Download CSV</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {});

        function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
            var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;
            data = args.data || null;
            if (data == null || !data.length) {
                return null;
            }
            columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
            lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';
            keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
            result = '';
            result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
            result += lineDelimiter;
            data.forEach(function(item) {
                ctr = 0;
                keys.forEach(function(key) {
                    if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;
                    result += item[key];
                    ctr++;
                    console.log("columnDelimiter " + result);
                });
                result += lineDelimiter;
            });
            return result;

        }

        function downloadCSV(args) {
            var youtubeData = [];
            var data, filename, link;

            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?part=snippet&videoId=PRU2ShMzQRg&key=""', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                for(var k = 0; k < data.items.length; k++) {
                youtubeData.push({
                    "videoid": data.items[k].id,
                    "Id": data.items[k].snippet.categoryId,
                    "ChannelId": data.items[k].snippet.channelId,
                    "Title": data.items[k].snippet.title,
                    // "Description": data.items[i].snippet.description.replace("\n", ""),
                    "Commentcount": data.items[k].statistics.commentCount,
                    "ViewCount": data.items[k].statistics.viewCount,
                    "LikeCount": data.items[k].statistics.likeCount,
                    "DislikeCount": data.items[k].statistics.dislikeCount,
                    "FavoriteCount": data.items[k].statistics.favoriteCount
                });
            }
                var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
                    data: youtubeData
                });
                if (csv == null) return;

                filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

                if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
                    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
                }
                data = encodeURI(csv);

                link = document.createElement('a');
                link.setAttribute('href', data);
                link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                link.click();
            });


        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Firstly move  $(document).ready(function() {}); out of the body and put it in the head. Then put all you JS inside that function.

Comment: You could just use `$.postJSON`

Comment: You are using http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ which is a GET HTTP request function? Shouldn't you use https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ instead?

Comment: $.postJSON is not working.Can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: I'm sorry. there is no`$.postJSON`, just `$.post`

Comment: can you please edit the code in the function downloadcsv.Because we cannot pass the whole url like this itseems  :https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems?fields=lineItems&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ to know how to use jquery POST

**Edited as requested**: send the request data like this:

```
        var postData = { 
              fields: "lineItems",
              key: "{YOUR_API_KEY}"
        }
        $.post('https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems',postData, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            for(var k = 0; k < data.items.length; k++) {
              youtubeData.push({
                "videoid": data.items[k].id,
                "Id": data.items[k].snippet.categoryId,
                "ChannelId": data.items[k].snippet.channelId,
                "Title": data.items[k].snippet.title,
                // "Description": data.items[i].snippet.description.replace("\n", ""),
                "Commentcount": data.items[k].statistics.commentCount,
                "ViewCount": data.items[k].statistics.viewCount,
                "LikeCount": data.items[k].statistics.likeCount,
                "DislikeCount": data.items[k].statistics.dislikeCount,
                "FavoriteCount": data.items[k].statistics.favoriteCount
              });
            }
            var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
                data: youtubeData
            });
            if (csv == null) return;

            filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

            if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
                csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
            }
            data = encodeURI(csv);

            link = document.createElement('a');
            link.setAttribute('href', data);
            link.setAttribute('download', filename);
            link.click();
        });
```

Comment: yea i have seen.but i am not able to do for that post API.i am not getting what to pass data from that api.can you please edit the code.

Comment: can you please replace with this URL https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems?fields=lineItems&key={YOUR_API_KEY}.because particularly i am not not able to do this with this API

Comment: so what about the for statement.It is not belongs to that API

Comment: removing that data inside for statement what can i pass inside that?

Comment: That for statement i kept for getjson.So for post request how to do?

Comment: you can see the response `data` returned from the API by console.log(data); or by using break point in Browser Developer Tool. After knowing which fields contained in `data`, do whatever you want to do regarding your need

Comment: "That for statement i kept for getjson.So for post request how to do? " - it is exactly the same in post

Comment: yes it is the same.And the Post URL is not working.I am getting 401 error()

Comment: jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4 POST https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems 401 () ..   I am getting this error

Comment: In API explorer i am getting the json response correctly.It will generate the API na.THe same API i sent you.That post URL.But if i put in code it is not working

Comment: what do you mean by "And the Post URL is not working.I am getting 401 error()"? How you got that error? Have you seen it on Developer Tools > Network ? Please check what the Console in Developer Tools says

Comment: yes some authentication error.unauthorized user it is saying

Comment: it looks like your API key is incorrect or expired? then this is not coding problem

Comment: Hi i am working in designing a chat-bot for eCommerce website using API.ai. I am able to create a chabot for single category(tv) and with respective filters like(price,brand etc..).Now i want to do for multiple categories with the multiple filters.How can we do that,can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `$.getJSON` with this

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?part=snippet&videoId=PRU2ShMzQRg&key=""'
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    for(var k = 0; k < data.items.length; k++) {
        youtubeData.push({
            "videoid": data.items[k].id,
            "Id": data.items[k].snippet.categoryId,
            "ChannelId": data.items[k].snippet.channelId,
            "Title": data.items[k].snippet.title,
            // "Description": data.items[i].snippet.description.replace("\n", ""),
            "Commentcount": data.items[k].statistics.commentCount,
            "ViewCount": data.items[k].statistics.viewCount,
            "LikeCount": data.items[k].statistics.likeCount,
            "DislikeCount": data.items[k].statistics.dislikeCount,
            "FavoriteCount": data.items[k].statistics.favoriteCount
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: yea for this API it is working.But for the Above API which i mentioned on the top it is not working..can you please create a new function and tell me how to do that.please

Comment: i want to know how to do post request for this :POST https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems?fields=lineItems&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: you can use `$.post` instead of `$getJSON`

Comment: syntax for post function `$.post(url, data, function)`

Comment: please edit the main code and send me.Because i tried a lot and i am not getting how to do that

Comment: instead of the youtube API please put this: https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/lineitems/downloadlineitems?fields=lineItems&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: else write an seperate function in that code.and send me please

Comment: so that i can understand easily.and even i can learn how to do

Comment: I can't open the link you've given

Comment: I'll try sending you the code later. I'm pretty busy right now.